# How to write a Regex for centrally aligned upper case words?

Tags: python, regex

```
                         THE COMPANY

ABCD is a new company in the field of Marketing. bla bla bla.

DESCRIPTION

xyz....                         

                         SUMMARY

asdf.......
```

For text like above, I want to pick up headings like THE COMPANY and SUMMARY. I would like to write a code in Python. I have been trying to use RegEx but have not found a way to write a pattern that matches centrally aligned words. I am open to any new method as long as it can be implemented in Python.

Comment: What do you mean by "centrally aligned"?

Comment: What is the exact **string** that you want to parse?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to match lines composed of some sort of indentation, followed by some number of upper case words.

If so, the following regex should do the trick:

```
(?m)^(?: +)[A-Z\s]+$
```

Let's take that piece by piece.

`(?m)` tells the regex matcher to treat `^` and `$` as the beginning and end of the line instead of the beginning and end of the string.

`^` matches the beginning of the line.

`(?: +)` is a non-capturing group of one or more spaces. In other words, this part of the pattern finds as many spaces as possible, and then ignores them. After all, we're not looking for the spaces, we're looking for the text. If you want the spaces too, just remove the `(?:` and `)`, leaving you with `\s+`. If you prefer tabs, replace `\s` with `\t`.

`[A-Z\s]+` matches one or more uppercase letters or whitespace characters.

`$` matches the end of the line.

Putting it all together (and into Python) we get:

```
import re
headers = re.findall('(?m)^(?:\s+)[A-Z\s]+$', your_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use re.match:

```
import re

example = '''                         THE COMPANY

ABCD is a new company in the field of Marketing. bla bla bla.

DESCRIPTION

xyz....                         

                         SUMMARY

asdf.......'''

headlines = []
for line in example.split('\n'):
    m = re.match(r'^\s{4,}([A-Z0-9 \t\._-]+)', line)
    if m:
        headlines.append(m.group(1))
print(headlines)
```

An other way is re.findall:

```
headlines = [x.lstrip(' \n') for x in re.findall(r'^\s{4,}[A-Z0-9 \t\._-]+', example, re.M)]
print(headlines)
```